# Any idea to improve the defined \righbrace as follows?

Tags: right-brace

I define the `\rightbrace` to produce desired right braces as follows. Is there any idea to improve the commands?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\udots{%
\mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise\p@
\vbox{\kern7\p@\hbox{.}}\mkern2mu
\raise4\p@\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7\p@\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}

\newcommand*\rightbrace[3]{\raisebox{#1em}{$\left.\makebox(0em,#2em){}\right\}{\scriptsize#3}$}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
2^{2^{\udots^2}}\rightbrace{0.5}{1}{n+1}=2^{2^n}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: having the first two arguments gives you full control but is a bit weird, I'd have taken the power of 2 left hand term as the argument and measured that, made a brace and then raised the brace to sit on the baseline  (see delarray package for example)

Answer (score 2):

My proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tower}{mo}{%
  \mathord{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th #1^{#1^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle#1\mathstrut}}}}}$}%
    \copy\z@
    \IfValueT{#2}{%
      \sbox\tw@{%
        $\m@th\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
        \vcenter to \ht\z@{}\right\rbrace\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle #2$}}$%
      }%
      \raisebox{\dimeval{\depth-0.5\delimitershortfall}}{\box\tw@}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\tower{2}$

$\tower{2}[n]$

$\tower{2}[n+1]=2^{2^n}$

$\tower{y}$

$\tower{f}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good solution. While what I focus on is how to produce right brace with instructions, suitable size and suitable baseline. Maybe we could get some idea from the definition of `\underbrace` or `\overbrace`.